# How to escape angle brackets in YAML?

Tags: yaml, escaping

OAS:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: User Management API
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080/api
paths:

  /users:
    get:
      summary: "Find all existing users"
      operationId: findAll
      responses:
        '200':
          description: "Users found. Response: List<User>"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
    ...
```

Checking SwaggerUI, I noticed the description is just

> Users found. Response: List

when it should be

> Users found. Response: List<User>

How do I escape the angle brackets?

Comment: The only satisfactory version so far was "Users found. Response: `List<User>`", ie. with backtics.

Comment: Data in the field `description` of the YAML file itself is exactly `Users found. Response: List<User>` (angle brackets has no special meaning in YAML specification). The problem is on SwaggerUI side. That is, escaping you are searching for is specific for SWaggerUI. You probably need to add an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI allows for Markdown in the `description` field. [Relevant part of the specification](https://swagger.io/specification/):

> Throughout the specification `description` fields are noted as supporting CommonMark markdown formatting. Where OpenAPI tooling renders rich text it MUST support, at a minimum, markdown syntax as described by CommonMark 0.27. Tooling MAY choose to ignore some CommonMark features to address security concerns.

Markdown allows for inline HTML tags, [as described in the CommonMark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.27/#raw-html):

> Text between `<` and `>` that looks like an HTML tag is parsed as a raw HTML tag and will be rendered in HTML without escaping. Tag and attribute names are not limited to current HTML tags, so custom tags (and even, say, DocBook tags) may be used.

`<User>` *looks* like an inline HTML tag. Therefore when showing the description, it is not rendered as text, but ignored because it's an invalid HTML tag.

The solution is to write `List&lt;User&gt;`.

Comment: Is there a way to change the markdown variant used in the specific OAS? If not, is it possible that there are some "interpreters" that won't decode `&lt;` as `<` and the text will therefore be almost unreadable?

Comment: @s3c Edited answer with relevant spec quotes. It references specifically CommonMark 0.27, though the „*at a mimimum*“ part suggests that tooling can deviate as long as the deviation is considered to have „more“ features, whatever that means. The CommonMark spec also requires support for HTML entities. Since Markdown support is only required for tooling rendering rich text, there may be tools that do not support Markdown, specifically CLI-based ones. I don't know if there actually are any. If you are this concerned about it, I recommend simply writing `List[User]` which also is common syntax.